# Defining a recursive sequence

Tags: recursion

I want to define a recursive sequence and then ask Mathematica to print a specific value:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, you need to use "delayed substitution" so that Mathematica knows it needs to wait with evaluating expression until you type `G[1]`. Secondly, you can't have arithmetic expression on the left-hand side. so the second line should be:

```
G[y_]:=2G[y-1].
```

Comment: y_ doesn't have anything to do with delayed substitution. It just means *any argument (indicated by _), to be named y*. If you leave away the underscore the call would work only for the literal symbol y.

Comment: Also it's not strictly true that you can't have an arithmetic expression on the left hand side; it just gives completely different semantics from the one intended: The original definition would have been used when calling as `G[y+1]` (assuming `y` has no value assigned at the point of call). Indeed, when using a pattern, it can even make sense to have arithmetic arguments, e.g.: `G[0]:=1;G[i_Integer/;i>0]:=2*G[i-1];G[y_+n_Integer/;n>0]:=2*G[y+n-1]` Then you could write `G[a+4]` and get the result `16*G[a]`.

Comment: @celtschk Hi, could you explain if there is a difference between those two functions : `H := Function[If[# <= 0, 0, H[# - 1] + #]]`  and `G = Function[If[# <= 0, 0, r := G[# - 1] + #; r ]]` ?